# how to use other libraries and classes in agile toolkit?

Tags: atk4

We have lot's of classes that in simple PHP applications we can use them simply like this:

```
require_once "path_to_lib" ;
$lib = new Mylib();
```

now how can we use these classes in agile toolkit? can we use theme directly in pages and models?

if we should use add-ons could you please give me a simple example with a require in it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use any PHP classes as you have discribed, or you can install them by [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) and autoload class of Composer will do the trick with automatic loading of required class.

Add the following into composer.json then run `php composer.phar update`:

```
{
    "include-path": ["lib/"]
}
```

Make sure you include Composer's auto-load from the `index.php`

Answer (score 1):

It's just a PHP so you can use it anywhere BUT this is NOT AGILE way.

One notice.
Use require_once "path_to_lib" ; outside of class

like

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/blah/blah.php';
class blah extends blahblah{
```

use new  inside class

```
$blah = new Blah();
```

The GOOD way is to create an addon and use it where you need to.

Comment: Thanks and if want to obey agile rules, how should we do that?

Comment: if we should use add-ons could you please give me a simple example with a require in it?